# Как сделать так чтобы телеграм бот записывал сообщение пользователя и отправлял его как запрос на сайт wiki через библиотеку wikipedia?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, wikipedia

Итак сегодня я столкнулся с проблемой при написании телеграм бота.Идея заключалась в том чтобы ты писал боту запрос а он тебе кидал в текстовом формате краткую статью вики(как я уже написал в заголовке через библиотеку wikipedia) но получилось так что бот отправлял не последнее сообщение как запрос а саму команду которая вызывала всю эту радость(search).

```html
import telebot
from telebot import types, TeleBot
import wikipedia

bot: TeleBot = telebot.TeleBot('BOT TOKEN')

def short(mess):
    features = "html.parser"
    wikipedia.set_lang("ru")
    c = wikipedia.summary(mess, sentences=100)
    return c

def search_2(message):
    getin = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, short(getin), parse_mode="html")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['search'])
def search(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что тебя интересует?")
    search_2(message)
```

вот так выглядел код.

Я пробовал:

Обнулять переменную(Возможно я делал это неправильно)

```
def search(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что тебя интересует?")
    getin = message.text
    getin = ""
    getin = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, short(getin), parse_mode="html")
```

Также пробовал выполнять команду search через 2 функции(то есть в функции search я использовал функцию search_2) это последний мой вариант кода который я представил ранее.

И да это первый мой вопрос на этом сайте поэтому не судите строго за корявость оформления этого вопроса)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import wikipedia
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['search'])
def search(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что тебя интересует?')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def wiki(message: types.Message):
    result = wikipedia.summary(message.text, sentences=5)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать так чтобы команду search можно было остановить?

Comment: Можно, но раз вы задаете такие вопросы, то вам стоит для начала изучить сам python, прежде чем начинать писать ботов. Ну или хотя бы посмотреть гайд, как этих самых ботов делать

Comment: Хорошо спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно, ты ведь передаешь в функцию search-2 , сам текст команды, создай ещё 1 хэндлер который будет принимать текстовое сообщение от пользователя и добавляй текст из этого сообщения.